# Weird localhost certificate problem after windows 10 update 2004 in all of my browsers! How can I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, firefox, https, ssl-certificate

I'm working on my project with SSL-enabled in Visual Studio 2019 16.7.3, everything was ok; Yesterday I updated my Windows 10 to version 2004 build 19041.508 and after that, any projects with localhost certificate goes wrong! I created a project with default asp.net core template and it has the same error.

Testing with Google Chrome v85, Firefox v80, Edge, IE, Brave.

I tried some ways in SO and other links found in google, but nothing could fix my problem!
Some of them are :

- Deleting ".vs" hidden folder and obj folder
- Clearing all localhost certificates in my computer (UserCertificates, ComputerCertificates) and generating again (VS prompts to create it)
- Disabling my Internet Security features (to don't intercept any HTTPS connections!)
- Uninstalling the VS and installing again
- netsh winsock reset
- Testing with Kestrel and IIS Express
- And some other ways...

[image]
[image]

BTW, I can't find any error details or logs for this.

Comment: Did you try to reset winsock by running command `netsh winsock reset` in cmd?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Kaspersky was responsible for this: I upgraded my Kaspersky to a new version (21.2.16.590) and now my problem is fixed

[Kaspersky SSL issue on localhost](https://forum.kaspersky.com/topic/my-visual-studio-projects-not-running-on-self-ssl-12611/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue and was about to attempt reinstalling VS2019 out of desperation.
A colleague of mine suggested to repair the VS installation instead, which I did. Then after building and starting one of my projects, I was prompted with this:

[image]

After clicking yes, I got another dialog asking me to accept the self signed certificate from IISExpress.
And then everything went back to normal for me.

But if this doesn't work, another workaround I can suggest is to get your solution running in VS code. It worked for me but not with all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

run as admin CMD or PowerShell then go to C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express address with cd Command Prompt then write this command:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express> ./IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:"Your port number for ssl"/ -UseSelfSigned
```

then rebuild and run your project.